# unable to save state for a list of animated widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Code for saving state of different page as below:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:workouttimer/view/TimerView.dart';
import 'package:workouttimer/view/IntervalTimerView.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Home(),
  theme: ThemeData(
    canvasColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    accentColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    TimerView(
      key: PageStorageKey('Timer'),
    ),
    IntervalTimerView(
      key: PageStorageKey('Interval Timer'),
    ),
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  Widget _bottomNavigationBar(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
    currentIndex: selectedIndex,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.av_timer), title: Text('Timer')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.timer), title: Text('Interval Timer')),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Workout Timer", style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white
      )),
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => exit(0),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.exit_to_app,  // add custom icons also
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,),
      bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_selectedIndex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code for the timer page is this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class TimerView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TimerView({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<TimerView> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  int time = 10;
  List<AnimationController> listOfTimer = [];
  List<int> listOfTiming = [];
  List<String> listOfDisplayTiming = [];
  bool loading = true;

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  loadJson() async {

      String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/timer_data.json');
      var jsonResult = json.decode(data);
      for (int i=0; i<jsonResult.length;i ++){
        listOfTiming.add(jsonResult[i]);
      }
      for (int i=0; i<listOfTiming.length;i ++){
        controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this,
          duration: Duration(seconds: listOfTiming[i]),
        );
        listOfTimer.add(controller);
      }
      setState(() {

      });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadJson();
    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:ListView.builder
          (
            itemCount: listOfTimer.length ,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return _listItem(index);
            }

        )
    );
  }

  _listItem(index) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white70,
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.65,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: AnimatedBuilder(
                      animation: listOfTimer[index],
                      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                        // the display of pink countdown circle
                        return CustomPaint(
                          painter: TimerPainter(
                            animation: listOfTimer[index],
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            color: Colors.orange,
                          ),
                          willChange: true,
                        );

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    // the display of timer countdown
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        "Timer",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedBuilder(
                          animation: listOfTimer[index],
                          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {

                            return Countdown(
                              animation: StepTween(
                                begin: listOfTiming[index],
                                end: 0,
                              ).animate(listOfTimer[index]),
                            );

                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      child: AnimatedBuilder(
                        animation: listOfTimer[index],
                        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                          return Icon(listOfTimer[index].isAnimating
                              ? Icons.pause
                              : Icons.play_arrow,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          );

//                           Icon(isPlaying
//                           ? Icons.pause
//                           : Icons.play_arrow);
                        },
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        // setState(() => isPlaying = !isPlaying);

                        if (listOfTimer[index].isAnimating) {
                          listOfTimer[index].stop(canceled: true);
                        } else {
                          listOfTimer[index].reverse(
                              from: listOfTimer[index].value == 0.0
                                  ? 1.0
                                  : listOfTimer[index].value);
                        }
                      },
                      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class TimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  TimerPainter({
    this.animation,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.color,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Color backgroundColor, color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    paint.color = color;
    double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
    canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & Size(size.width, size.width), math.pi * 1.5, progress, false, paint);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(TimerPainter old) {
    return animation.value != old.animation.value ||
        color != old.color ||
        backgroundColor != old.backgroundColor;
  }
}

class Countdown extends AnimatedWidget {
  Countdown({Key key, this.animation}) : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    Duration clockTimer = Duration(seconds: animation.value);

    String timerText =
        '${clockTimer.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString()}:${clockTimer.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';

    return Text(
      "$timerText",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that the state of the timer and the scroll axis will not be saved when I move to another page. It will always restart the page and shift to view to the topmost. Any idea of how I can save the state?

Comment: You can try `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

Comment: Thx, will read into it if I cannot find where the problem lies.